# How does C compiler decide whether to call library function or system call

Tags: c, function, compiler-construction, system-calls

I know that `read` is system call. But when I read `man 2 and  man 3`  of read it shows me different explanation. So , I am suspecting that `read` has library function and system call. In such case if I use `read` in my c program, whether compiler will consider read as `library` function or `system call` Please explain me on this confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't. System calls are present in libc (the C standard library) just like library functions are. The implementations of system calls in libc are just "stubs" which invoke system-specific methods of calling into the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're on Linux. On that platform, the manpage `read(2)` describes the Linux system call, while `read(3)` describes the POSIX specification for `read`, if you have the POSIX manpages installed. The latter is in category `3` because POSIX doesn't specify a difference between system calls and library functions.

There's only one `read` in libc, which is (a thin wrapper around) the system call.